# ошибка "cannot assign to value: 'index' is a 'let' constant"

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

```
let str = "Guten Tag!"
let alph = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "x", "t", "u", "v", "w", "s", "y", "z"]
var schtchik = 0

for index in str.characters.indices {
    for i in alph {
        if index = i {
            schtchik += 1
        }
    }
    if schtchik > 26 {
        print("")
    } else {
        print("")
    }
}
```

Задача с [hackerrank.com](http://hackerrank.com)
Вам задана строка , состоящая из пробелов и латинских букв. Строка называется панграммой, если она содержит каждую из 26 латинских букв хотя бы раз. Определите является ли строка  панграммой.

Вопрос как ее решить?

Comment: собеседование проходите? :)

Comment: проходил позавчера) ну там не пошло не много . а сейчас для себя решил порешать

Comment: сначала избавиться от пробелов, на всякий случай можно сконвертировать всю строку в строчные буквы; потом например создать массив из 26 булеанов, и пройти по всей строке присваивая булеану на соответствующем месте true; в конце посмотреть чтоб все 26 были true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Я бы решил эту задачу так:**

```
let str = "Guten Tag!"

let allowed = NSCharacterSet.init(charactersInString: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")
let trimmed = str.lowercaseString.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(allowed.invertedSet).joinWithSeparator("")
let count = NSSet.init(array: trimmed.characters.map{String($0)}).count

print(count == 26 ? "Это панаграмма" : "Это не панаграмма")
```

**Это ваш вариант с исправленными ошибками:**

```
let str = "Guten Tag!"
let alph: [Character] = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "x", "t", "u", "v", "w", "s", "y", "z"]
var schtchik = 0

for letter in str.lowercaseString.characters {
    for i in alph {
        if letter == i {
            schtchik += 1
        }
    }
}

if schtchik == 26 {
    print("YES")
} else {
    print("NO")
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Максимально приближенно к Вашему варианту:

```
let str = "qwertyuiopASDFGHJKLzxcvbnmddsfsfssdfsf" //наша строка
var alph: [Character] = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "x", "t", "u", "v", "w", "s", "y", "z"] //алфавит, Вы упустили "i"
var counter = 0

for ch in str.lowercaseString.characters {
    //вариант 1
    if alph.contains(ch) { //есть ли нужный символ
        counter += 1 
        alph.removeAtIndex(alph.indexOf(ch)!) //т.к. мы его уже учли, удаляем из массива, он нам больше не нужен.
    }
    //вариант 2 (на выбор)
    /*
    for i in 0..<alph.count {
        if ch == alph[i] {
            counter += 1
            alph.removeAtIndex(i)
            break
        }
    }
    */
}

print("\(counter == 26 ? "панаграмма" : "печалька")")
```

Answer (score 2):

ну или можно извернуться, и сконвертировать строку в NSSet и просто посмотреть что в сете 26 элементов

```
NSString *test = @"qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm";

test = [test stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];

unsigned int len = [test length];
char buffer[len];

strncpy(buffer, [test UTF8String], len);

NSMutableSet *chars = [NSMutableSet new];
for(int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
    char current = buffer[i];
    [chars addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", current]];
}

NSLog(@"is %@ pangram", (chars.count == 26 ? @"" : @"NOT"));
```

Swift:

```
var test: NSString = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm"

test = test.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "")

let len = test.length

let buffer: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8> = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>.alloc(len)

strncpy(buffer, test.UTF8String, len)


let chars:NSMutableSet = NSMutableSet()
for i in 0 ..< len {
    let current = buffer[i]
    chars.addObject(NSString.localizedStringWithFormat("%c", current))
}

print("is \(chars.count == 26 ? "" : "NOT") pangram")
```

Comment: А если на swifte

Comment: ну имея код на ОбжС можно уже и самому сконвертировать. добавил в ответ

Comment: Спасибо. еще вопрос есть более схожий метод(тупой\простой\влоб\вмногострок) решения этого задания с тем что пытался сделать я ?

Comment: то, что я в комментарии к вопросу написал можно сделать